# Complexity of the following piece of code: log log n or log n?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I think the following code is `O(log log n)` because it has `i*i` in it but I am confused between `log n` and `log (log n)`.

```
for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) 
{
   if (number % i == 0) return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's `O(sqrt(number))`.

Comment: You might want to refresh your understanding of Big Oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the code to the following:

```
for (i=2; i<=sqrt(number); i++) 
{
   if (number % i == 0) return 0;
}
```

And then:

[image]

Comment: how theta , why not big O ?

Comment: Since it's big theta, then it's big O, and big Omega.
Sometimes, one cannot know the exact formula of a summation, and then some approximation has to be made (e.g T(n) <= 2sqrt(n)), here we I am sure it's most likely upperbounding, therefore, I would definitely use Big O.
In the case of the question, I am 100% positive the number of iterations is strictly equal to what is obtained in there, big theta.
Take a look Limit Method Process: http://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/S06-235/files/Asymptotics-HandoutNoNotes.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Your loop condition is equivalent to i <= sqrt(number) so you will have about sqrt(number) iterations in worst case.

so complexity of this code is O(√n) (O(sqrt(n))

Comment: sorry but didn't understood what u said ? what is O(sqrt(n))

Comment: sqrt - square root of n

Comment: is it equivalent to log n ?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi I think you need to refresh your maths. That square roots are not the same as logarithms is a fairly basic fact.

Answer (score 1):

Write several examples and compute the number of iterations. When you estimate the complexity you may only consider the worst case - when `number` is prime. Also you may search for the complexity of this algorithm of checking if a number is prime in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) for instance.

HINT: complexity has nothing to do with logarithm, but more like another arithmetic function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the number is prime, it should come out much less than sqrt(number) iterations. In case number is prime, then number of times it iterates is max floor(sqrt(number)), so that's the complexity, O(sqrt(number))